# How to use CommonsMultipartResolver in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons

I have tried to use CommonsMultipartResolver in Boot translating my old application (WAR) to Boot, and right now it got the following code:

```
@Configuration
    public class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean openEntityManagerFilterRegistrationBean() {
            // Set upload filter
            final MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
            final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(multipartFilter);
            filterRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("multipartResolverBeanName", "commonsMultipartResolver");

            return filterRegistrationBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
            final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);

            return commonsMultipartResolver;
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way in Boot, cause a I saw some properties to be applied in application.properties. Would they be the same purpose than defining a FilterRegistrationBean?

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.file-size-threshold=0 # Threshold after which files will be written to disk.
multipart.location= # Intermediate location of uploaded files.
multipart.max-file-size=1Mb # Max file size.
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb # Max request size.
```

Could anyone provide any sample how to use it? Thanks.

By the way, It tried to set the property "multipart.enabled=true" and I got:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'enabled' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties]: Bean property 'enabled' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:927)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:749)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:645)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:121)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:630)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:296)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3209) in Spring Boot and will be fixed in 1.2.5.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no **enabled** property in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties` class.

Refer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java

If you are using Servlet 3 container you no need to use commons-fileupload mechanism and Multipart support is enabled by default. If you don't want to customize any multipart default config no need to add any config in `application.properties` as well.

```
<form method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File: <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile)
{
    System.out.println(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

If you want to use commons-fileupload then adding following configuration is working fine:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
        final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean multipartFilterRegistrationBean() {
        final MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(multipartFilter);
        filterRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("multipartResolverBeanName", "commonsMultipartResolver");
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

And of course we need to add commons-fileupload dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Actually that configuration is flawed, the name of the bean should be `multipartResolver` instead of `comonsMultipartResolver` if you want proper integration with the `DispatcherServlet`. Also the filter isn't mandatory (only if you are combining it with Spring Security it is).

Comment: There indeed isn't an `enabled` property in that class however the property should match [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java#L51) to enable/disable multipart configuration. So basically I consider that an issue in the multipart config part of Spring Boot. Also not all properties do need to have a corresponding class to be mapped to, there are also other means of using properties defined in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: If you look at Spring Boot documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html there's a property "multipart.enabled=true" and there says enabled value. Why it exists if it's not valid so?

Comment: "multipart.enabled=false" is used to disable boot's multipart autoconfiguraiton https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java#L51

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `CommonsMultipartFile` to upload a file, please add `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})` in your spring boot project. Disable the multi-part configuration in spring boot.

```
   public RespDataView provisionalMediaUpload(@RequestParam("file") CommonsMultipartFile file,
                                               @RequestParam("type") String type) {}
```