# File upload - MultipartResolver implementation

Tags: grails

I'm dumping the old question content since it's overly complicated.
It's simple now.

How to change the multipartResolver from the standard:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver
```

to

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver
```

?

I'm failing to do so with Grails v3.2.6.

I've tried various things mentioned here (declaring the beans, filters, disabling MultipartAutoConfiguration):

- [Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723871/required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present/29411814#29411814)
- [How to use CommonsMultipartResolver in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768242/how-to-use-commonsmultipartresolver-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about changing the implementation but I did have to change the respective config settings in application.yml to someting like...

```
grails:
   controllers:
       upload:
           maxRequestSize: 10000
           maxFileSize:  10000

multipart:
    maxRequestSize: 5MB
    maxFileSize:  5MB
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried that on a clean Grail 3.2.6 example project and I'm still getting the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` as the multipartResolver bean